# Why is scale subtracted when dividing BigInteger and added when multiplying?

Tags: java, division, bigdecimal, bignum

I have data that I'm trying to accurately and precisely manipulate with an ever-increasing denominator.

Please assume that the numerator will always have a decimal.

I see in the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#divide%28java.math.BigDecimal%29) that `divide(BigDecimal divisor)` will actually reduce the scale which seems strange since as I understand the usage of "scale", number of digits past the decimal point, it should increase upon division.

I also see in the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#multiply%28java.math.BigDecimal%29) that `multiply(BigDecimal multiplicand)` increases the scale.  This also doesn't make sense, according to my understanding of scale, since the likelihood of two multiplied numbers needing digits beyond the decimal point goes down.

Are these typos in the docs?

If not, is my understanding of scale incorrect?

If not, how can precision be maintained with an ever-increasing denominator that increases the number of digits past the decimal point?

Comment: Not sure I understood your overall purpose here, but if this purpose is to achieve "infinite" precision, then you can implement a RationalNumber class which will maintain a pair of BigIntegers {numerator,denominator}, so that you will "lose" information only when you print the number in decimal (or any other base) format.

Comment: @barakmanos I apologize barak manos.  I wasn't really sure of much not even what the question actually was.  Please note edit.  Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is effectively just [*scientific notation*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation).  As it says in the docs, the value of a `BigDecimal` is:

```
unscaledValue × 10^(-scale)
```

Thus multiplying two `BigDecimal`s is equivalent to multiplying their `unscaledValue`s and adding their `scale`s:

```
   a * b
== (uA * 10^-sA) * (uB * 10^-sB)
== (uA * uB) * 10^-(sA + sB)
```

Comment: Thank you Oli Charlesworth!  This is for a `BigDecimal`.  Even still, if the scale decreases with division, `unscaledValue` increases while multiplication decreases, if it's true that scale decreases with division and increases with multiplication.  Please help me understand.  Thank you so very much in advance!

Comment: @Gracchus: We have `a * b == (uA * 10^-sA) * (uB * 10^-sB) == (uA * uB) * 10^-(sA+sB)`.

Comment: That is genius!  Thank you so very very much Oli Charlesworth!